# How to use DynamoDB export_table_to_point_in_time boto3?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I got error when trying to use IncrementalExport which fail the validation for "ExportType" and "IncrementalExportSpecification". I'm using the latest boto3 1.28.79. I follow the documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb/client/export_table_to_point_in_time.html)

```
client.export_table_to_point_in_time(
            TableArn=table_arn,
            S3Bucket=s3_bucket_name,
            ExportFormat='DYNAMODB_JSON',
            ExportType='INCREMENTAL_EXPORT',
            IncrementalExportSpecification={
                'ExportFromTime': datetime.today(),
                'ExportToTime': datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1),
                'ExportViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'
            }
        )
```

Error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in input: \"ExportType\", must be one of: TableArn, ExportTime, ClientToken, S3Bucket, S3BucketOwner, S3Prefix, S3SseAlgorithm, S3SseKmsKeyId, ExportFormat\nUnknown parameter in input: \"IncrementalExportSpecification\", must be one of: TableArn, ExportTime, ClientToken, S3Bucket, S3BucketOwner, S3Prefix, S3SseAlgorithm, S3SseKmsKeyId, ExportFormat",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "requestId": "e0edeed9-d68d-4f8c-ae4f-030e05248061",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datadog_lambda/wrapper.py\", line 214, in __call__\n    self.response = self.func(event, context, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/src/eda_transaction_export_handler.py\", line 15, in handle\n    def handle(events, context):\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ddtrace/contrib/aws_lambda/patch.py\", line 120, in __call__\n    self.response = self.func(*args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/src/eda_transaction_export_handler.py\", line 16, in handle\n    client.export_table_to_point_in_time(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 530, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ddtrace/contrib/botocore/patch.py\", line 680, in patched_api_call\n    result = original_func(*args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 919, in _make_api_call\n    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 990, in _convert_to_request_dict\n    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py\", line 381, in serialize_to_request\n    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the correct version of `boto3`? Can you run `pip freeze` in the relevant context (project venv if one is used or such) and show the output?

Comment: aws-lambda-powertools==2.26.0
boto3==1.28.78
botocore==1.31.78
fastjsonschema==2.18.1
jmespath==1.0.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
s3transfer==0.7.0
six==1.16.0
typing_extensions==4.8.0
urllib3==1.26.18

This is the output @Uberhumus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the latest version of `boto3==1.28.79`,
`botocore==1.31.79`. I was able to export the data with no issue:

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
table_arn = 'arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:<account-id>:table/<my-table>'
s3_bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
from_time = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
to_time = datetime.today()
try:
    dynamodb.export_table_to_point_in_time(
                TableArn=table_arn,
                S3Bucket=s3_bucket_name,
                ExportFormat='DYNAMODB_JSON',
                ExportType='INCREMENTAL_EXPORT',
                IncrementalExportSpecification={
                    'ExportFromTime': from_time,
                    'ExportToTime': to_time,
                    'ExportViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'
                }
            )
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

[image]

Comment: There is a problem when I build the lambda layer and the boto3 version is not correct. Not a problem with boto3. Thanks guys!